# JAVA Android studio secure socket ssl connect to server socket ssl windows 10

Tags: java, android-studio, ssl, windows-10

In java jdk I created certificat ssl for socket server using **keytool**
I have app **server socket** in a position Listening and certificat stored on app server (PC Windows 10).

How can android client connect using certificat to server windows 10?

what is the method I use in android studio to create certificate and its type with the code used in  socket client. The code socket server is below (Windows 10):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;

public class ServerSSL {
  private static ServerSocket server;
  private static int port = 1004;
  private static ObjectInputStream ois;
  private static ObjectOutputStream oos;
  private static Socket socket;
  
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ServerSocket server = ((SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault()).createServerSocket(port);
    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Socket socket;
        while (true) {
          try {
            socket = server.accept();
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            String message = "";
            String recMsg = "";
            try {
              message = (String) ois.readObject();
              switch (message) {
                case "clientSend":
                  recMsg = (String) ois.readObject();
                  System.out.println(recMsg);
                  break;
              }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    });
    th.start();
    try {
      ois.close();
      oos.close();
      socket.close();
      server.close();
    } catch (NullPointerException z) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain what you try to accomplish? do you want to access the server on the android app? do you use emulator?

Comment: Access from android emulator to server using ssl socket